# how could I set more than one type of input style in CSS in the same brackets(not big parentheses)?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a Web UI framework and when I deal with `input` , I have to write the type over and over again with the same style. In that case, I want to put them together to shink the size of the file.

This is my code:

```css
input[class=tUI][type=date],[class=tUI][type=month],[class=tUI][type=week],[class=tUI][type=time] {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="week" class="tUI">
```

I want to define the type by just using one Brackets. For example, I want `input[class=tUI][type=date || week || month]` **by just using CSS**

How could I get that? Or is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
input.tUI:is([type=date],[type=month],[type=week],[type=time]) {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="week" class="tUI" />
<input type="date" class="tUI" />
```